# AWS Create Instance from LAMBDA with ROLE Python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create EC2 instance from LAMBDA and assign IAM role to the EC2 instance. The EC2 instance requires the role as there are some S3 related functionality. I have created an AMI with the required softwares installed.
I have no issues in creating the new instance from this AMI and assigning role to the EC2 instance.

My Issue: I created 2 EC2 instance with same role assigned to both of them (same LAMBDA Script).   When I try executing the python script, in 1 EC2 instance it executes as expected. But in the second instance it fails with error "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials". (It is expecting credentials). I checked the role assigned to both the instance they are the same. I am using the default VPC, the only difference i see is different subnet for both these instance. I tried creating multiple instances using the same lambda script, all the instance in "Subnet A" executed properly. But the instances in "Subnet B" had the access issues.

Question: When assigning role to EC2 via Lambda, do we need to set any other parameter. Can anyone please help me on how to resolve this.

Lambda Code to create instance:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')
    response = ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami-XXXXXXXXXX’,
                     InstanceType='t2.micro',
                     MinCount=1, MaxCount=1,
                     SecurityGroupIds=['AWS_EC2_XXXXXX’],
                     KeyName='AWS_XXXXX_KEY',
                     IamInstanceProfile={
                         'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:instance-profile/AWS_EC2_SQS_S3_ROLE'
                     }
                   )
```

**EC2 instance-1 (No Issues):**
[image]

**EC2 instance-2 (Has Issues):**

[image]

Comment: There should be no connection between the subnet and an `Unable to locate credentials` error. Are you able to use the AWS CLI on the 'not working' instances? For example, run `aws s3 ls` to list buckets. It should use the same credentials as a Python program. Were both instances launched from the same AMI, with nothing different run on them (eg no Environment Variables changed)?

Comment: Thx John. Let me try this and see if it works.